# Line detection in python from a picture

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, hough-transform

I am currently trying to do a line detection on an image of this type:

[image: Original picture taken from my phone]

The top and bottom black bars are just due to where I took the picture, not due to resizing or anything.

I used the following code:

```
image = cv2.imread('test_2.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 100, 250)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 25, minLineLength=100, maxLineGap=50)

hough = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)

for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(hough, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 255, 255), 2)

cv2.imwrite('hough.jpg', hough)
```

And I got those lines at the end:

[image: hough.jpg]

Is there any concept I could use that would help me?

I have tried changing the different parameters to the `Canny` and `HoughLinesP` calls, but it doesn't seem to help.

Edit: I'm trying to detect all the lines on the picture. The 3 horizontal lines, as well as all the vertical lines(crossing or just on top of the horizontal line) as well as the slanted lines.
My main issues are that some of the vertical lines aren't appearing, and every line has 2 hough lines instead of just one, which is what I need.
I think I can easily deal with the double line issue, but I'm not sure how to deal with the missing lines.

Comment: You didn't tell us what you want as a result.

Comment: Sorry, it seemed obvious to me. I have edited my post to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hough is looking for edges, and you have ridges instead. This explains the double lines.

As your image is easy to binarize, you can try by edge thinning. You will get nice, continuous stretches of pixels from which you can infer line segments. But you may have to "repair" those that are crossed by a long line.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at what line thinning is.

Comment: @Yves Daoust do you have code for the image above ?

Comment: @Link: sorry, this was made with a commercial software. You can find an implementation of thinning here: https://github.com/erich666/GraphicsGems/blob/master/gemsiv/thin_image.c